How do I get more support skill gem slots for my skill gems?
Every skill in PoE 2 has two support gem slots and I was wondering how I could get more?
I've already filled up 2/2 supports.


I haven't played 2 yet but if it works similarly to 1, you just need to wait for higher level areas. Equipment in 1 had a cap on sockets based on ilvl, and the same thing may be  happening here.

In Path of Exile 2 you need to find a currency called Jeweller Orb.
There three kind of Jeweller Orbs, Lesser, Greater and Perfect.
Lesser Jeweller Orb drop from Area level 25 or higher
Greater Jeweller Orb drop from Area level 45 or higher
Perfect Jeweller Orb drop from Area level 65 or higher
Those currency have to be used on the gem skill itself and will add one supprt each one. In particular:

From 2 to 3 support skill slot, you have to use a Lesser Jeweller Orb

From 3 to 4 support skill slot, you have to use a Greater Jeweller Orb

From 4 to 5 support skill slot, you have to use a Perfect Jeweller Orb


